# Highcharts Solid Gauge behaves differently when both the min and max values are 0

Tags: highcharts

[image]

Notice the graph on the right. I want a 0 on the left side and the right side of the pane and an empty gauge when I have both the min and max set to 0. Instead if fills the gauge up half way with only one 0 in the center. My code below.

```
      Highcharts.chart element[0],
        chart: 
          type: 'solidgauge'
          backgroundColor: null
          credits: enabled: false
        title: text: scope.title
        pane:
          center: [
            '50%'
            '85%'
          ]
          size: '140%'
          startAngle: -90
          endAngle: 90
          background:
            backgroundColor: null
            innerRadius: '60%'
            outerRadius: '100%'
            shape: 'arc'
        exporting: enabled: false
        tooltip: enabled: false
        plotOptions: solidgauge: dataLabels:
          y: 5
          borderWidth: 0
          useHTML: true
        yAxis:
          min: 0
          max: 0
          title: text: null
          lineWidth: 0
          tickWidth: 0
          minorTickInterval: null
          tickPixelInterval: null
        credits: enabled: false
        series: [ {
          name: null
          data: [ 0 ]
          dataLabels: format: '<div class="label-format"><span class="data-label">{y}</span></div>'
          tooltip: valueSuffix: null
        } ]
```

Comment: I think that I don't understand your way of thinking. Why have you set the min and max to 0? What output do you expect? For me, more natural is to set some range, like here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t25v1zfu/

Comment: The max in these charts are dynamic. In the 3rd chart it is 0 right now but thats not always the case.

Comment: so what output do you expect when the max is set to 0 and value is also 0?

Comment: I would like it to look like the other two charts. Empty with zeros on either side.

Comment: Have you considered to use `null` data instead of `0`? Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n20awopm/